# Is speaking during the khutba, but outside the mesjid allowed?

Tags: jumuah, khutbah

During school days, they let us use the school bus to go to a mesjid for Salatul Jumu'ah. When we go to the ground around the mesjid (which has the bathroom and the wudu place), I notice a lot of people speaking there even when the khutba has started. But they're speaking **outside** the mesjid, and from outside we can kind of hear the Khutba (but not very clearly) from the electronic speakers at the mesjid. In this case, is talking during Khutba also make you gain nothing but laghw (idle talk)? Jazakum Allah khayran,